# How to parse json and read in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I have this code in my project:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
Dim reader As StreamReader

request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://url.to.my.json"), HttpWebRequest)

response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

Dim rawresp As String
rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()
textbox2.text = rawresp
```

and TextBox2 gets the JSON code correctly.

and this is my JSON code example:

```
{
  "id":174543706,
  "first_name":"Hamed",
  "last_name":"Ap",
  "username":"hamed_ap",
  "type":"private"
}
```

My question:

How to get **174543706** from JSON code ("id") into TextBox3.Text???

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(JObject.Parse(jstr)("id"))`

Comment: @plutonix error of jstr ! i should use rawresp instead ?

Answer (score 17):

You could use `JavaScriptSerializer` which is in `System.Web.Script.Serialization`.

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        Dim s As String

        Try
            Dim rawresp As String = "{""id"":174543706,""first_name"":""Hamed"",""last_name"":""Ap"",""username"":""hamed_ap"",""type"":""private""}"

            Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(rawresp)

            s = dict("id")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: error for :Dim jss As New **JavaScriptSerializer()**

Comment: @Ali Add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions`.

Comment: This error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll

Additional information: Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Comment: @Ali - I updated my answer with the code I used.  Note that I am targeting Framework 4.5.

Comment: i use this code : `Try

            Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(rawresp)

            TextBox1.Text = dict("id")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try`

nothing happend

Comment: @Ali You still need to get `rawresp` they way you were previously.  I hardcoded the JSON to simulate what you were doing.

Comment: i notice that my json code has many id ! is there any diffrent ?

Comment: Yes, that would be different because the JSON would not be the same.

Comment: we should add or import package System.Web.Extensions to add System.Web.Script.Serialization .

Answer (score 7):

try this code :

```
Dim jsonResulttodict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(rawresp)
Dim firstItem = jsonResulttodict.item ("id")
```

hope it help you !!

Comment: 'jsonResult' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

How to add this ?

Comment: I've modified the code that was a mistake sorry ! Try it now !

Answer (score 3):

How to get 174543706 from JSON code ("id") into `TextBox3.Text`?

```
{
  "id": 174543706,
  "first_name": "Hamed",
  "last_name": "Ap",
  "username": "hamed_ap",
  "type": "private"
}
```

Sorry if my reply was late. I hope my answer can help someone who's still confused.
So what you do was get the response and read the JSON.

After you do `ReadToEnd()`:

```
Dim xr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(rawresp))
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(rawresp)
```

Then What you need to do is to read the data from the response. you do like this:

```
Dim res As String = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc)
Dim ThisToken As JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(res)
Dim response As String = ThisToken("response").ToString()
Dim ThisData As JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(response)
```

After that yo can get the data from the response and convert it into string

```
Dim idx As String = ThisData("id").ToString()

// the value of idx will be: 174543706
```

Then last you can put it into `Texbox3.Text`.

Answer (score 2):

JSON can be parsed using adding Newtonsoft.Json.dll reference

Code :

```
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim json As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://time.jsontest.com/")
        Dim parsejson As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
        Dim thedate = parsejson.SelectToken("date").ToString()
        txt1.Text = "Date Is "+thedate
    End Sub
End Class
```

Reference : [Narendra Dwivedi - Parse JSON](https://www.narendradwivedi.org/2022/04/parse-json-vb-net.html)

Answer (score 1):

**This works:**

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
Dim reader As StreamReader

request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://url.to.my.json"), HttpWebRequest)

response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

Dim rawresp As String
rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()


textbox2.text = JObject.Parse(rawresp)("id")
```