# How to read JSON data and put it in Combo Box and TextBox in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

Issue 1

I have a JSON web response which I need to display in Combobox.

```
{"PRODUCTS": ["Product1","Product2","Product3","Product4","5"]}
```

Issue 2

I have two separate texboxes like `Stock1txtBox` and `Stock2txtBox`. Now I need to display "LASTTRADEPRICE" of STOCK 1 from the following JSON web response to `Stock1txtbox` and same way i need to display "LASTTRADEPRICE" of STOCK 2 to `Stock2txtbox`. Please give some example.

```
[
{
"BUYPRICE": 0,
"EXCHANGE": "IDX",
"INSTRUMENTIDENTIFIER": "STOCK 1",
"LASTTRADEPRICE": 597.2,
"LASTTRADETIME": 1569580196000,
"SELLPRICE": 597.2
},
{
"BUYPRICE": 218.1,
"EXCHANGE": "IDX",
"INSTRUMENTIDENTIFIER": "STOC 2",
"LASTTRADEPRICE": 218.1,
"LASTTRADETIME": 1569580193000,
"SELLPRICE": 0
}
]
```

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943260/how-to-parse-json-and-read-in-vb-net) or [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for info on deserializing JSON data.

Comment: Provide full json if possible, you can also look at some my previous answers on json for hints (they contain everything you need though)