# How to read a property from json response in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I am calling a rest webservice with parameters **start** and **limit** to get the user details for 2 users only.

Here is the json response.

```
{"start":11, "limit":2,"count":800,
"previous": "start=9&limit=10",
"next":"start=13&Limit=2",
"results":[{"user":"a11"},{"user":"a12"}]}
```

I need to read the **"start=13&Limit=2"** value  of next property . Can anyone please suggest a way to read it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse json and read in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943260/how-to-parse-json-and-read-in-vb-net)

Comment: add json.net then dim something as string = jobject.parse(yourjson)("next").value(of string)