# Extract IP Addresses from JSON file using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

is there a way to extract only IPv4 from a file in JSON language using VB.net

For example I would like that when I open a JSON file from VB I can filter only IPv4 from this text for example: `https://pastebin.com/raw/S7Vnnxqa`

& i expect the results like this `https://pastebin.com/raw/8L8Ckrwi` i founded this website that he offer a tool to do that `https://www.toolsvoid.com/extract-ip-addresses/` i put the link here to understand more what i mean but i don't want to use an external tool i want it to be converted from VB directly thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your "text" is JSON. Load it using the JSON parser of your choice (google `VB.NET parse JSON`), loop over the `matches` array and read the IP address from the `http.host` property of each element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse json and read in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943260/how-to-parse-json-and-read-in-vb-net)

Comment: Hi @CherryDT thank you for your answer but it's not what i expect to do i wan't to past for exemple this JSON text in textbox and when i click for exemple convert to ipv4 he change the textbox into this results for exemple https://pastebin.com/raw/8L8Ckrwi  similar as this only ipv4 without {} and stuffs thank you anyway

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly what I said: You'd read the JSON text from the textbox, parse it to an object, loop over the `matches` array on it and push the `http.host` of each element (which is the IP) into an array, and then you'd join the array with newlines and put it into the textbox again. Then you get the result that you described.

Comment: Unless of course you want to accept _any_ sort of text as input and just blindly get anything the _looks_ like an IP address, in which case you could use a regular expression (google `VB.NET IP regex` to see what I mean). But if you get the input always in this format, I'd recommend parsing it properly instead.

Comment: Can you help me with an exemple of code please i don't know this method thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Sure, adding as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "text" is JSON. Load it using the JSON parser of your choice (google VB.NET parse JSON), loop over the `matches` array and read the IP address from the `http.host` property of each element.

Here is an example how to do it using the `Newtonsoft.Json` package (see it working [here on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rJP6l4)):

```vb
' Assume that the variable myJsonString contains the original string

Dim myJObject = JObject.Parse(myJsonString)
For Each match In myJObject("matches")
    Console.WriteLine(match("http")("host"))
Next
```

Output:

```
62.176.84.198
197.214.169.59
46.234.76.75
122.136.141.67
219.73.94.83
2402:800:621b:33f1:d1e3:5544:4fcf:526e
178.136.75.125
188.167.212.252
...
```

If you want to extract only IPv4 and not IPv6, you can use a regular expression to check whether it matches:

```vb
Dim IPV4Regex = New Regex("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$")

Dim ip = match("http")("host")
If IPV4Regex.Match(ip).Success Then
  Console.WriteLine(ip)
End If
```

```
62.176.84.198
197.214.169.59
46.234.76.75
122.136.141.67
219.73.94.83
178.136.75.125
188.167.212.252
...
```

Of course it's always recommended to parse the input data in a structured way, to avoid surprises such as false positives. But if you just want to match *anything* that looks like an IP address, regardless of the input format (even if you just put `hello1.2.3.4world` in the textbox), then you could use just the regular expression and skip the structured approach (see it working [here on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5VAUiO)):

```vb
Dim IPV4RegexWithWordBoundary = New Regex("\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b")

Dim match = IPV4RegexWithWordBoundary.Match(myJsonString)
Do While match.Success
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
    match = match.NextMatch()
Loop
```

Here I modified the regular expression to use `\b...\b` instead of `^...$` so that it matches word boundaries instead of start/end of string. Note however that now we get IP addresses *twice* with the input that you provided, because the addresses exist more than once:

```
62.176.84.198
62.176.84.198
197.214.169.59
197.214.169.59
46.234.76.75
46.234.76.75
...
```

Comment: The [IPAddress.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) can be used to check for valid IP addresses too.