# VB.NET, I can't convert Unicode escape sequences to text

Tags: vb.net

I watched many videos on YouTube, read many solutions on Google and Stack Overflow! Can anyone tell me how I can convert Unicode escape sequences to text?

I tried this:

```
Dim f = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("sa3444444d4ds\u0040outllok.com")
MsgBox(f)
```

and this:

```
Dim f = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString("sa3444444d4ds\u0040outllok.com")
MsgBox(f)
```

and this:

```
Dim myBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("sa3444444d4ds\u0040outllok.com")

Dim myChars As Char() = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(myBytes)
Dim myString As String = New String(myChars)
MsgBox(myString)
```

and this:

```
    Dim f = UnicodeToAscii("sa3444444d4ds\u0040outllok.com")

    MsgBox(f)

Public Function UnicodeToAscii(ByVal unicodeString As String) As String

    Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.ASCII
    Dim unicode As Encoding = Encoding.Unicode
    ' Convert the string into a byte array. 
    Dim unicodeBytes As Byte() = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString)

    ' Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other. 
    Dim asciiBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes)

    ' Convert the new byte array into a char array and then into a string. 
    Dim asciiChars(ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length) - 1) As Char
    ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0)
    Dim asciiString As New String(asciiChars)
    Return asciiString
End Function
```

Comment: Where is this string coming from? Maybe you can avoid receiving escaped chars if you specify the source and how you get it.

Comment: from the webbrowser, html source

Comment: `how Can convert unicode to text` - strings are already unicode in .Net. The `\u0040` is a possible way of representing Unicode that may be used in some contexts, such as the C# string literals or JSON text. If this piece is a part of a json response, then [parse it as json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38943260/11683).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Regex.Unescape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=netcore-3.1).

For example,

```
Dim s = "sa3444444d4ds\u0040outllok.com"
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Unescape(s))
```

outputs:

> sa3444444d4ds@outllok.com

Credit to Tim Patrick for showing this in the Visual Studio Magazine article [Overcoming Escape Sequence Envy in Visual Basic and C#](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/08/01/overcoming-escape-sequence-envy.aspx).